# Do variables within functions persist in RAM at all times on Arduinos?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, arduino

I have quite a big Arduino sketch that is pushing the limits of available memory on the processor.  As is I'm freeing up memory and reducing my use of global variables as much as possible.  I'm using `MemoryFree.h` (details can be found [here](http://arduino.cc/playground/Code/AvailableMemory)) to check available memory.  I have a working sketch (too long to post here) but when I add another function with a few variables (that are within what I consider available memory) my system crashes or halts due to no memory.

I added the following function:

```
boolean moved(){

int yreadings[4];
int zreadings[4];


free(&yreadings);
free(&zreadings);
}
```

I then added to my main loop the following code:

```
 Serial.print("Mem is ");
 Serial.println(freeMemory());
 moved();
```

If `moved()` in the loop and the entire function below are commented out I get an output of

```
Mem is 499
```

on each iteration, suggesting no loss of memory per iteration.

Yet if I uncomment the function and the calling of it out I get the following output:

```
Mem is 499
Mem is -16094
```

on the first and second lines before crashing...

Even if memory is persistant shouldn't this only use much less than the entire 499 bytes per iteration?  Still, how am I losing ANY memory at all?

UPDATE:
Even more strange:  if I remove the moved() function and declare the integer arrays globally I STILL get memory readins of 499.  How is that so?  Shouldn't it be decreased by the amount of memory 24 integers consume?

Comment: You shouldn't `free` memory in automatic storage. Remove `free(&yreadings); free(&yreadings);` What do you get now?

Comment: Things run much smoother by removing that.  At least for a while.  It ends up crashing a few iterations later though....  Removing this function allows it to run for a while with no issue...  I do get persistant 499 values by removing the free() calls.

Comment: @WildBill Frankly it sounds like you don't understand the way memory works in c++ at all. Perhaps you should look for a basic introduction. You want to understand three classes: global and function static data (often said to be "in the data segment"); automatic (often said to be "on the stack" though the standard doesn't use the phrase); and dynamic allocations in the free store (often said to be "on the heap").

Comment: I thought I did but what I don't understand is why I have the same memory count in the main loop despite the location of declaration of those arrays?  If they are declared globally or within a function why would the memory count be the same OUTSIDE of the function call?  Shouldn't I lose memory upon the declaration of each global variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need automatic storage to exist for only part of the execution of a function you can place them inside a scope block:

```
void foo(void) {

   // some code where neither reading variable is occupying memory

   {
      int yreadings[4];
      int zreadings[4];

      // here these variable are taking up memory

   }

   // other code where neither reading variable is occupying memory
}
```

but of course you can only use them in that block.

---

To expand on my comment there are three classes of memory use that have different durations

- Globals and variables declared `static` in function or method or class context exist for the entire life of the program
- Automatic variables (those declared inside a function or method) exist for the lifetime of their scope including the life of any other subprograms called from that scope
- Dynamic allocations are blocks of memory obtained from `new`<sup>1</sup> or the `alloc` family of function (which will always be a bit larger than the size you request for bookkeeping reasons) which persist from the time you allocate them until you call `delete` or `free` (respectively).

---

<sup>1</sup> If you override `new` this may or may not still apply, but if you do that it is your lookout to understand what you've done to yourself.

Comment: I've considered that but haven't done it yet, primarily due to the last bit that I added to my question.  I think I am missing something here with my discovery of free memory.

Comment: I understand that global variables exist for the life of the program, hence why I'm confused as to why free memory is the same during the main loop if I declare my variables globally or use automatic variables...

Comment: The other thing to understand here is *exactly* what `freeMemory` is returning. Does it know about the stack pointer? Does it know how much free store is actually in use, the size of the largest free block or just the address of the highest allocation?